# Maven missing [INFO] in CLI output

Tags: command-line-interface, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.6.3 on windows 10, since yesterday the [INFO][WARNING] Tags are missing . It happend mid development.

Also i'm hosting a wildfly 10 Application Server.

I tried to switch to an newer Version, same issue.
It's working in Ubunutu (WSL) i use the same settings.xml .

Output i get:

[image: Windows10 Output]

Ouput i should get (from WSL):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it was in someways related to my JDK. After i tried out a newer Version it worked again.

After some research, it seems my wildfly start configuration killed my JDK.